# Pivot pandas timeseries by year

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a shorter or more elegant way to pivot a timeseries by year in pandas? The code below does what I want but I wonder if there is a better way to accomplish this:

```
import pandas
import numpy

daterange = pandas.date_range(start='2000-01-01', end='2017-12-31', freq='10T')
# generate a fake timeseries of measured wind speeds from 2000 to 2017 in 10min intervals
wind_speed = pandas.Series(data=numpy.random.rand(daterange.size), index=daterange)
# group by year
wind_speed_groups = wind_speed.groupby(wind_speed.index.year).groups
# assemble data frame with columns of wind speed data for every year
wind_speed_pivot = pandas.DataFrame()
for key, group in wind_speed_groups.items():
    series = wind_speed[group]
    series.name = key
    series.index = series.index - pandas.Timestamp(str(key)+'-01-01')
    wind_speed_pivot = wind_speed_pivot.join(series, how='outer')
print(wind_speed_pivot)
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on CodeReview.

Comment: @Deena: run the script and you get the result as it should be.. big table, column names from '2000' to '2017' (years), index from '0days 00:00:00' to '365days 00:00:00' (timedelta), filled with wind speed data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the fastest method, as I'm adding two columns to your initial dataframe (it's possible to add just one if you want to overwrite it).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
daterange = pd.date_range(start='2000-01-01', end='2017-12-31', freq='10T')
# generate a fake timeseries of measured wind speeds from 2000 to 2017 in 10min intervals
wind_speed = pd.Series(data=np.random.rand(daterange.size), index=daterange)

df = wind_speed.to_frame("windspeed")
df["year"] = df.index.year
df["pv_index"] = df.index - df["year"].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime(x,1,1))
wind_speed_pivot = df.pivot_table(index=["pv_index"], columns=["year"], values=["windspeed"])
```

Comment: Thank's! Speed doesn't matter in this case.